# Tornado or Django works with CGI?

Tags: python, django, cgi, webserver, tornado

Tornado is a webserver + framework like Django but for real-time features.

On my server I don't have a python module or wsgi module so I thought 
CGI. 
Is there a way to get Tornado ( or Django ) works by using CGI folder ? 
If yes, Could you explain me how do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) provides a CGI-to-WSGI adapter, but you really should consider using something like FastCGI instead.

Comment: I want use CGI only for test. Why FastCGI or Wsgi is better ?

Comment: CGI starts up the whole process per request. Something as large as Django takes several seconds to start up. FastCGI and WSGI (can) run the Django project as a separate app and just send messages back and forth between it and the web server, so the process doesn't have to be started up each time.

Comment: django has a development server which is great for testing.

Answer (score 5):

Main feature of Tornado is that it is high performance web-server written in Python, for creating web applications using Python programming language.

Running Tornado as CGI application negates the very reason it exists, because running CGI scripts is expensive in terms of performance, and most probably there is no way to run Tornado as CGI script.