# How do I get a CGI script to run under on a Tornado web server?

Tags: python, cgi, tornado

I'm trying out several web servers. Today I'm trying out the [Tornado web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_(web_server)).

One of the first things I do when I try out a new web server is get the web server to run my test CGI script.

I see a bunch of information at http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html about how to get the Tornado web server to run scripts that use the WSGI protocol (it involves WSGIContainer).
But I don't see anything at the tornadoweb.org site about how to get the Tornado web server to run scripts that use the CGI protocol. (Am I overlooking something? Is there maybe somewhere else that talks about getting a Tornado web server to execute CGI scripts?)

I'm mystified, because literally every other web server I've ever tried out has some way to run CGI scripts using the standard CGI protocol.

My Tornado web server is simply serving up the my CGI script file as text on my web browser screen; as far as I can tell it never executes the CGI script.
(Perhaps I've missed some essential configuration step?)

Am I missing some documentation that tells how to persuade Tornado to execute the CGI script, rather than copy it to the web browser? Please link to it.

Do maybe people who run the Tornado web server always run some *other* web server to handle CGI scripts? Please link to something that shows how I can get Tornado and some other web server to run more-or-less simultaneously on the same machine and split up their duties.

(This is not a duplicate of the "
[Tornado or Django works with CGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537065/tornado-or-django-works-with-cgi)
" question
which asks how to get tornado to run *as* a CGI script under some other web server application. In my case, tornado is the *only* web server application on this machine, and I'm trying to get some simple CGI script to run under Tornado).

Comment: You can probably hack up some way of doing this but it sounds like a bad idea and defeats the purpose of Tornado as an async server/framework. In terms of running Tornado alongside CGI scripts, you probably should use a proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado does not support CGI. Tornado is not a general-purpose web server in the way that Apache and nginx are; it is designed to run applications built with the Tornado framework (i.e. `tornado.web.RequestHandler` and friends). There is some interoperability with other frameworks via the WSGI module, and it would be possible to implement CGI on top of Tornado's HTTPServer, it's kind of missing the point.

Many Tornado users run nginx as a proxy in front of a Tornado server, and nginx can also run CGI, so this would be a good way to incorporate CGI into your setup if you need it.